# Impedance of transformer

Tags: power, transformer, impedance

The percent impedance of a power transformer (%Z*) is handy for fault analysis, but isn't sufficient information for nominal circuit analysis.

Why don't power transformer nameplates/specs have a complete (R + X j) rating. Or do they? Is there a resource out there with typical values based on transformer type and size? Or even a general guidance as to the ratio of R to X (winding resistance to reactance) for power transformers?

Comment: Transformers either come with a datasheet or is built to your specification. The information is either available there or can be calculated from the given information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the value of R you would need the value of the transformer losses (from the data sheet or test report). Unfortunately, the value of losses is not an information that is required by standards to appear on the nameplate that comes with the transformer.

The standards, unfortunately, do not provide this 'typical' information either (IEC 60076-5, for example, has tables for suggested minimum impedance values and system short-circuit apparent power based on voltage, but nothing about X/ R).

You can look for a manufacturer's catalog (they usually contain the losses) and if you find a transformer with the same power and voltages ratings, it would probably be a good approximation.